# R's tm_map is creating non-existing words

Tags: r, tm, tidytext

I'm using `tm` package to find associations between words in a text.

This is what I did (I'm also using `tidytext` package)

```
book <- Corpus(VectorSource(c(part1,part2,part3,part4,part5)))
book <- tm_map(book, content_transformer(tolower))
book <- tm_map(book, removeNumbers)
book <- tm_map(book, removePunctuation)
book <- tm_map(book, stripWhitespace)
book <- tm_map(book, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

TDM_book <- TermDocumentMatrix(book)

book_tidy <- tidy(TDM_book)
```

When I check my final table there are words like `informationare` but in the text there's noting like `information are` in the text but lots of `information this` and `information that`.

How can I get rid of that "magic pasting"?

Best regards

Comment: can you share your sample data?

Comment: the only problem is that I'm using copyrighted material... let me try to recreate that with something obtained from Gutenberg

Comment: Did you check for "information <stopword>+ are"?

Comment: yes, this is weird but after some weird tests I found that ctrl+f and to replace " " by " " (blank spaces) worked :S